# Are there any problems with creating multiple HTTP server objects in a Node.js application?

Tags: node.js

In a Node.js application I would like to split a single API into 2 APIs - one public and one internal to a VPN environment.

Currently:

```js
import { createServer } from 'http'

const api = createServer((req, res) => ...).listen(3000) // Nginx proxies to localhost:3000
```

But that makes all my routes available on a public interface. I could limit access to certain routes based on the incoming `req` object properties. But that does not seem very secure to me, since I know it's possible to set the host header for an HTTP request (and I assume many other ways to spoof network request origins - I'm not comfortable enough with HTTP to attempt securing the API in this way).

Instead I would like to do this:

```js
import { createServer } from 'http'

const pubApi = createServer((req, res) => ...).listen(3000)
const intApi = createServer((req, res) => ...).listen(4000)
```

I can tell this works, but I don't know if there are any drawbacks to this approach? This seems semantically a bit strange, since I would have normally expected a Node.js process to correspond to a single HTTP server. But then again... why not host multiple webservers in a single Node.js application?

Why not host many webservers in a Node.js process?

```js
const httpServers = appDefinitions.reduce(
  (apps, {cb, port}) => {
    const server = createServer(cb)
    server.listen(port)
    return [...apps, server]
  },
  []
)
```

I'm specifically interested to know if there is any objective reason as to whether this is a good idea or not, and any drawbacks to this approach. I imagine that an HTTP server is a light process and that hosting 2 servers in a single Node.js process is fine. But I'm not at all sure on this.

I'm also interested in general opinions!

Comment: I think that HTTP Proxy Middleware serves exactly for this purpose.

Comment: None. You can create as many as you want. But do ensure that the server you are listening to are listening to correctly and you fetch the right server object. The way you did a reduce, it is actually impossible to capture the server object for any need later on. I did recommend map the server Def's for listening into arrays. Second is use any prod server manager which is highly recommended

Comment: Thank you - I have not tested the reduce code (but will update it now to hopefully be more useful)

Comment: @Gary. Actually... `createServer().listen()` does seem to return the server object. Why did you say I couldn't capture the server object?

Answer (score 0):

Although HTTP server is a light process but hosting multiple servers in the same process will have significant impact on the performance.

As Node.js application runs on **single thread** and if you are running multiple servers in a single process and if one of them is having some CPU intensive code it will block the process for requests from other server as well. you will not feel very significant changes if your requests are less. but once your request frequency will increase it will have impact on the performance of your servers.

So I think it's better to run multiple servers in separate processes so that one's execution flow does not affect the number of requests served by the other one.

Comment: depends on the cpu as well, if it is some AWS instance with a single core and you hit 100% usage it will block the others too. But still you have benefit to that to split the servers into two files, because you have two event loops running separately and blocking one of them may not block the other

Comment: well in this case the server WOULD have previously been dealing with the same requests. Being aware of the limitations of Node.js as a single thread process is true, but not necessarily related to splitting http servers in this case since the purpose isn't load handling

Comment: You can run multiple servers in the same script using multiple processes without modifying the code. Just launch your app using the cluster module. A lot of process managers can do this for you (instead of you having to write the cluster script). For example you can run the server using PM2 cluster mode: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

Comment: thanks @slebetman - that is useful to know. In this case the servers are running different code though